# Wireshark filter payload after completed dissection

Tags: protocol-buffers, wireshark, network-protocols, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to write a dissector where I need to filter the packets after a dissection depending on the values on a certain field.

For example, I have the following tree after my dissector is finished:

```
  Header
     Msg_Length: 10
     Car_Model: 1334
     Car_Speed: 25
     Error_Code: 1 (True)
  Content
     Distance_Left: 20
     Engine_Fail: 0
```

I would like to filter my capture so that Wireshark only displays the packets with a "Car_Speed" higher than 30. Preferably when writing something like: "my_proto.car_speed > 30"  in the display filter search box.

P.S I have several different types of messages in my capture and I'd like to be able to filter on different criteria in each. D.S

Comment: How are you writing a dissector? Using the C or Lua API? Or using some other generator?

Comment: I'm writing it in Lua. Though, it now seems like I have solved it. I had to declare all (200+) ProtoField before starting the dissector, which was a bit of a hassle... Then find the corresponding fields by the use of global dynamic variables. Maybe not the best way, but it currently works

Comment: If you can include your current code (what you have tried) maybe we can offer suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Regrettably, I can't include code snippets since the material is not my property and altering the content would be a lot of work.

Though, if you could explain to me the function and purpose of a ProtoField (since I can't seem to find detailed information about it), that would be mighty helpful!